# PHP Login header location

Tags: php, header

I have the following code, but im blocked here..

```
<?php
require 'members/core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    if (strlen($password) > 18) {
        $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
    }
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
        header('Location: http://www.site.ro/1/index.html');
        exit();
    }
}
} 
?>
```

and the following:

```
<?php if ($page == 'login'): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone help me to combine that part of code?

I've tryed that, but tell me header already send..

```
<?php if ($page == 'login'): ?>
<?php
require 'members/core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    if (strlen($password) > 18) {
        $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
    }
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
        header('Location: http://www.site.ro/1/index.html');
        exit();
    }
}
} 
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Im beginner in php, so please understand me.
Thank you in advance.

Resolved !

That it's the final code:

```
<?php if ($page == 'login'):
require 'members/core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
} else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
} else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                 Please check your email.';
} else {
    if (strlen($password) > 18) {
        $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
    }
    $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
    }else {
        session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
        $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
        header('Location: http://www.site.ro/1/index.html');
        exit();
    }
}
} 
endif; ?>
```

Comment: If you write out any content (even a white space before the first <?php !) before header() you will see this error.

Comment: And here two blocks of `<?php ... ?>` are separated with new line which is being sent.

Comment: I know bro.. That's why i ask for your help !

Comment: So you are sure there is no content before this login script? No php warning or notices?

Answer (score 2):

Once any content is sent to the user, you can not modify headers. This includes any errant whitespace or line breaks.

```
<?php if ($page == 'login'): ?>
<?php
require 'members/core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();
```

You stop php execution long enough to send a single line break between lines 1 and 2.

Change this to the following and try again.

```
<?php if ($page == 'login'):

require 'members/core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();
```

Comment: That is the corect answer. U have my respect. Cheers bro !

Comment: Actually, it's best to close the question properly and click the white checkmark next to Castis' answer till it turns Green, since it was indeed the correct answer. @AvadaniiClaudiu

Answer (score 0):

You may have some whitespace somewhere in your code.

1. You can find it.
2. Or the easiest solution for this is to turn on [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php)

What output buffering allows you to do is echo/print anything you want, and still maintain the ability to send header info anywhere in your page.